# How to vertically center nodes' text for nodes positioned via above

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I have 2 nodes of different height. They are positioned relative to the nodes below them, b1 and b2, which are the same height and have the same y value.
I want b1, b2 to have the same horizontal distance as a1, a2 and I want them to be vertically centered.
But because a1, a2 have different lengths I can't just use `right=of b1` because the x value will not align with a2. Likewise `above=of a2` results in the wrong y-value.
I would like to have both `right=of b1` and `above=of a2` for my upper right node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \node [draw] (a1) {loooooooooong};
      \node [draw, right=of a1] (a2) {short};

      \node [draw, above=of a1] (b1) {$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$};
      \node [draw, blue, above=of a2] (b2) {$\dots$};
      \node [draw, green, right=of b1] (b3) {$\dots$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

one possibility is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \node [draw] (a1) {loooooooooong};
      \node [draw, right=of a1] (a2) {short};

      \node [draw, above=of a1] (b1) {$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$};
      \node [draw, blue, above=of a2] (b2) {$\dots$};
      \node [draw, green, at=(b1 -| a2)] (b3) {$\dots$}; % <---

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```